# Passive sense of intransitive verb in active voice

Tags: grammar

1) It happened two days ago. (correct)

2) It was happened two days ago.(incorrect)

I know the number (2) is incorrect as intransitive verb can't be passive. But how can the number 1 be correct?

because something happens by someone but not by itself, such as (It has been done by someone *not itself*), so we need a passive voice for number 1.

Would you mind explaining to me the details of this passive sense of active voice? I am confused.

Comment: Some stuff just happens and not through the intervention of some agent. Like beta decay. Intransitive verbs by definition do not license a direct object. They therefore cannot be transposed into the passive. There is no "passive sense of the active voice".

Comment: _Happen_ does not require an agent; it means "occur". Earthquakes happen; floods happen. Things happen, even. By themselves. The purpose of passive is to put the object up front where it gets more attention; but _It happened two days ago_ does not need any passive because it doesn't have any object.

Answer (score 0):

> *Happen* does not require an agent; it means "occur". Earthquakes happen; floods happen. Things happen, even. By themselves. The purpose of passive is to put the object up front where it gets more attention; but *It happened two days ago* does not need any passive because it doesn't have any object. – John Lawler